# cassandra-spark-connector error with repartitionByCassandraReplica function

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, connector

I'm trying to use the new join functionality from the 1.2 version but I get an error with the repartitionByCassandraReplica function in the repl.

I've tried to duplicate the example of the website and created a cassandra table (shopping_history) with a couple of elements :
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.mde

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.driver.core._

case class CustomerID(cust_id: Int)
val idsOfInterest = sc.parallelize(1 to 1000).map(CustomerID(_))
val repartitioned =  idsOfInterest.repartitionByCassandraReplica("cim_dev", "shopping_history", 10)
repartitioned.first()
```

I get this error :

```
15/04/13 18:35:43 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, dev2-cim.aid.fr): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $line31.$read$$iwC$$iwC$CustomerID
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:59)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$1.getNext(Serializer.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$27.apply(RDD.scala:1098)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$27.apply(RDD.scala:1098)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1353)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:1353)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I use spark 1.2.0 with connector 1.2.0 RC 3.
The joinWithCassandraTable function used on idsOfInterest works.

I'm also curious about the differences betwween : joinWithCassandraTable / cassandraTable with a In clause / foreachPartition(withSessionDo) syntax.

Do they all request the data to the local node which acts as a coordinator ?
Is joinWithCassandraTable combine with repartitionByCassandraReplica as efficient as an async query, requesting data only to the local node ? What happen if repartitionByCassandraReplica is not applied ?

I've already asked this question on the google group forum of the cassandra connector :
https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!topic/spark-connector-user/b615ANGSySc

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about your class loader issue without knowing how you are running this code, Could you give us your submit command or launch command?

Comment: @RussS, my launch command is spark-shell :) with spark.executor.extraClassPath / spark.driver.extraClassPath set in spark-default.conf to the cassandra connector jar. What is strange is that the class not found is created in the shell...

Comment: Are you using the full assembly? Also try --jars there is some classloader weirdness sometimes on some versions of spark.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer your second question here, and followup with the first portion if I can figure something out based on more information.

> I'm also curious about the differences betwween :
>   joinWithCassandraTable / cassandraTable with a In clause /
>   foreachPartition(withSessionDo) syntax.

The `cassandraTable` with an in Clause will create a single spark partition. So it may be allright for very small in clauses, but the clause must be serialized from the driver to the spark application. This could be really bad for large in clauses and in general we don't want to send data back and forth from the spark driver to the executors if we don't have to.

`joinWithCassandraTable` and `foreachPartition(withSessionDo)` are very similar. The main difference is that the joinWithCassandraTable call is using the Connector transformation and reading code which should make it much easier to get Scala objects out of your Cassandra Rows. In both of these cases your data stays in RDD form and won't get serialized back to the driver. They will also both use the partitioner from the previous RDD (or last RDD which exposes a preferredLocation method) so they will be able to do work with repartitionByCassandraTable.

If `repartitionByCassandraTable` is not applied the data will be requested on a node that may or may not be a coordinator for the information you are requesting. This will add an additional network hop in your query but this may not be a very large performance penalty. The times at which you want to repartition before joining really depend on the total volume of data and the cost of the spark shuffle in the repartition op.

Comment: Thanks for your answer RussS. I'm still curious about the "may or may not be a coordinator" part. Until now, I was using foreachPartition(withSessionDo) syntax with an IN clause to query some time series information on batchs of customerID (Part. Key) and I have experienced some problem with very large queries. I was wondering if each executor was querying the local cassandra as a coordinator generating a lot of network traffic and CPU load. That's why I'm interresting in the joinWithCassandraTable. So, when does an executor need a coordinator ? Is the behavior different between 1.1 and 1.2 ?

Comment: The in clause also performs a server side multiget which the join will not do. As for the coordinator, if there is only one multiget query you only get one coordinator per in.